# There was an unexpected error while creating the Cloud Platform project. Error code DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

We have a google apps script that runs on google sheets as a macro.

We have maybe a dozen scripts all which have been executing without issue. Suddenly today we are getting the following error on **every** script:

> "Script (NAME OF THE SCRIPT HERE) experienced an error"

The details link doesn't provide any extra detail.

If I open and attempt to run the script in the classic editor, I get the following error.

> We're sorry, there was an unexpected error while creating the Cloud
> Platform project. Error code DEADLINE_EXCEEDED.

Even when I update the funciton to me empty, such this:

```
function dropdownmenu(){
return
}
```

We are getting the same error.

Is there an unposted outage with google cloud services/app scripts? What could have possibly changed in our environment?

I should note, we have already tried changing the runtime version on our script:

[How to avoid DEADLINE_EXCEEDED when "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65104577/how-to-avoid-deadline-exceeded-when-were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-pleas)

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is an outage with Google Apps Script that may be affecting you, there are people reporting the same issue even when running simple functions in Apps Script, you can see Google's public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239136914) for more details.

There are some users that are reporting that the issue started to fix itself, try clearing cache and cookies in your browser and hopefully the issue gets fixed soon.

UPDATE: Based on comments in the issue tracker, adding your script ID to the Library might work too. To get the script ID, go to the menu on the left, go to "Project Settings", copy the script ID, go back to "Editor", click the plus icon next to "Libraries" and add the script ID.